# Does Google analytics plugin with phonegap apps for windows works?

Tags: phonegap-plugins

Does Google analytics plugin with phonegap apps for windows works? As i can't see anywhere. And if it works then please help me and let me know that how and which plugin work for windows phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Now it's supporting, microsoft makes its site as below, use its sdk and use universal google analytics tracking code.

https://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/